# Encapsulate function with submit and revealing module pattern

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

I am not sure if I understand this correctly.

The following example changes form action depending on a radio button selection. Then a javascript submit is executed.

I tried to build the whole thing after the revealing module pattern.

```
var myModule= (function () {

    function makeSubmit() {
        document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            var form= document.getElementById('form'),
                datasetURL = document.querySelector('input[name = "dataface"]:checked'),
                actionURL = datasetURL.dataset.url,
                searchterm= document.getElementById('searchterm').value,
                submit;

                (datasetURL.id == "db-01") ? submit = actionURL+searchterm: submit = actionURL;

                form.action = submit;
                form.submit(); 
            });
    }

     return {
        search: function () {
            makeSubmit();
     }
};
})();

$(document).ready(function () {
    myModule.search();
});
```

My question is now whether this procedure is so correct.
Basically it works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can pass private function as reference

`return {
        search: makesubmit
}`

And invoke it as you did.